# Executing awk command from python

Tags: python, linux, awk

I am trying to execute the following `awk` command from a python script

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="\t"}; {print $1"\t"$2}' file_a > file_b
```

For this, I tried to use `subprocess` as follows:

```
subprocess.check_output(["awk", 'BEGIN {FS="\t"}; {print $1"\t"$2}',
                         file_a, ">",
                         file_b])
```

where `file_a` and `file_b` are strings pointing to the path of the files.

From this, I am getting the error

> awk: cannot open > (No such file or directory)

I'm sure I'm inputing the arguments to `subprocess` in a wrong way, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: [Plumbum](https://plumbum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) might be interesting for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it may look like it in your shell of choice, `>`, `<`, and `|` are not actually passed as arguments to the program you run. Rather, they're a special part of the shell that the program never gets to see.

Since they're part of the shell, and not part of the OS or program, you have to **emulate their effects yourself** with the normal facilities the language gives you. In your case, since you're trying to pipe to a file, **simply use Python's `open()`** as you would normally. The `subprocess` API supports arguments to specify stdout, stdin, and stderr, and you can supply any file object for those.

Check it out:

```
with open(file_b, 'wb') as f:
    subprocess.call(["awk", 'BEGIN {FS="\t"}; {print $1"\t"$2}', file_a], stdout=f)
```

Since `subprocess.check_output` redirects output already, it doesn't take the `stdout` argument. Using `subprocess.call` avoids this. If you also need the output later in the script, you can instead assign the return value of `check_output` to a variable, and then save that to `file_b`.

If you use a lot of shell commands, you might also want to check out [Plumbum](https://plumbum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which gives you a large set of fairly silly shell-like operator overloads.

Comment: Very clear explanation, thanks! There's just ", file_a" missing in your code snippet, in the list given to check_output. I tried with check_output but it doesn't allow to set stdout. So I ended up using call.

Comment: @FilipeAleixo Ah, makes sense that it wouldn't. Its `help()` documentation has an example of setting stderr, so I figured stdout would be fine too - but I suppose it's not. Updating answer accordingly.